# How can I compress blob image when retrieving to database?

Tags: php, mysql, image, compression

Im using the following code to upload the image in my database:

```
<form>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit name="upload">
</form>
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydb");

  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $photo = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));

    $result=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO images_tbl(image) VALUES('$photo')");

?>
```

and retrieve the photo this way:

```
<?php
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT image FROM image_tbl");
    while ($test=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $getphoto = $test['image'];
    }
     echo'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($getphoto).'" style="width: 40px; 40px;" class="w3-round" draggable="false" /> ';
?>
```

When I upload a large image it loads the original file size. I want to optimize my website. Is there any way to compress the image when I retrieve them to the database so it loads faster to the website?

Comment: To store the image in my database. And retrieve it using base64_encode($image)

Comment: I see. Im using it because its working. Im uploading images to my database using that code. And also I can retrieve it. That's why I'm using it. I just want to know if there's a way to compress the image when I retreive it to the database. But you said its outdated. So maybe, I'll just change the way how I upload images to my database

Comment: Let me make it clear, this function doesn't do anything DB-related. It just adds slashes in front of every `'` and `"` in your string. You haven't show us the code which adds the files to the database. You didn't explain how you want to compress the image or why. Is JPEG compression what you are looking for? GZIP? Maybe something completely different. Please be clear about your requirements and show us what you tried. We would love to help, but there is not enough information here for us to even try to guess what you are doing .

Comment: My apologize. I edited it the best as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not adding images to the database. At least not a MySQL database.
Instead, try to store images in the filesystem and only store the filesystem path in the database.
Consider renaming the files to long unique random names and storing that along with the original filename in the database.

Using PHP you can serve your files using their original names:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filenameOriginal."\n");
readfile($filenameStorage);
```

MySQL is great att manipulating text, large blobs of binary data are a different story though. You should also ask yourself what you are gaining by storing images in the database.

About compression. Images are commonly compressed quite well so further compressing them for database storage is usually not feasible.

I would also strongly urge you to look into Prepared Statements for MySQL.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

That allows you to use queries like:

```
INSERT INTO images_tbl(image) VALUES(?)
```

The question mark signifies a variable which you pass to MySQL as binary with a separate function. This prevents SQL injection attacks which addslashes() definitely will not.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php